# Python- Retrieving data from a UDP server

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I've been trying to attempt this for a while now, but I haven't made progress.
I have betterjoy (not my program, reference here: github.com/Davidobot/BetterJoy )  which creates a local UDP server at 127.0.0.1:26760, and through wireshark and some other programs (such as padtest/dsu controller test), I am able to verify packets with motion data being are sent from the server.

What I am trying to do is write a program which can receive the data being sent from the server, however so far, I have not been able to receive packets with my own code. This is my first time working with UDP, so I've spent a lot of time going through tutorials on creating clients, but unfortunately I have not been able to get any packets.

This is the code I am working with right now:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 26760

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
                     
msg = "this is a message"
sock.sendto(msg.encode("utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print("message sent")
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
print("received message: %s" % data)
```

Most of it is taken directly from the UDP communication documentation for python. I have tried a few different client code snippets other than this, but they are all generally following this same structure, and none have worked in retrieving the packets. It might be worth noting that wireshark lists the packets sent from the server as "loopback traffic", though I don't know how important that is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the server code.  It should be replying to your message with something like `s.sendto(b'reply',addr)` where `addr` is the address received from `recvfrom`.  There's nothing wrong with the code shown.

Comment: Hi, I'm not 100% sure how to show the server code. The server is being created by someone else's program ( https://github.com/Davidobot/BetterJoy ) - It's not something that I can change easily. 
Still, if there is nothing wrong with the code, then it must be I am doing something wrong logically. Earlier, I tried to inspect the code that other programs use to get the motion data from betterjoy, such as dolphin's dsu client, but it was very confusing. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Took a very quick glance at the server. You may have to send a specific message to get a reply.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I have a general idea of how the message might be constructed, based on this documentation: https://v1993.github.io/cemuhook-protocol/
Ill try testing out a few different messages once I understand how to build a message to send.